# Когда в последний раз заходил пользователь php

Tags: php

У меня на базе данных имеется таблица USERS в нем таблицы login, password и last_date. Как мне сделать когда user заходить с логином и паролем  сохранить дату последнего входа в last_date, если есть примеры или сайты помогите пожалуйста

Comment: Вам нужно выполнить `UPDATE`

Comment: Ведите журнал входов. Заодно будете видеть, кого брутфорсят...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UPDATE USERS SET last_date = NOW() WHERE login='vasaya'
```

или

```
UPDATE USERS SET last_date = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) WHERE login='vasaya'
```